# PRINT a Dialogue in Javascript/jQUerycode

Tags: jquery, forms, css

Hi I have an enquiry form with PHP and i'd like to show a dialogue which displays error upon submit button.

Currently I am using Windows Alert method however it cant have any CSS so I'd like to use either CSS3 or Jquery to print the dialogue on screen.

Here is my code.

```
if( val == 'unemployed') 
{
alert("Unfortunately, we don't accept unemployed applications.");
    }
```

I have looked at this code but now sure how I can integrate it with PHP as as soon as I put the javascript in the above code, it gives error.

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal

Comment: Do you mean print on the screen or print on a printer?

Comment: Please include more of your code and the text of the error message.

Comment: PHP is a **server** side language, therefore it cannot display any dialogue messages on the **client**. YOu can use PHP to output javascript, that will then display the alert...

Comment: Hi I would like to print a message on the screen. All I need is replace win alert coding with any custom css or jquery dialogue so it doesnt look ugly.

Comment: Here is my PHP script. <script type="text/javascript">
function submitToCRM()
{ var val = $('[name="employment"] :selected').val(); } if( val == 'unemployed') 
{
alert("Unfortunately, we don't accept unemployed applications.");
    }

Comment: that's not PHP... DO you even use PHP? or just confuse names?

Comment: sorry its in javascript..but how can i show error message using css and not win alert.

Comment: @user3121064 in that case, midn to update the question? I already edited the title and tags, but the text still mentions PHP. ANd, while you'Re at it, please show us hwhat code you had (formatted and embedded into the quesiton) and what exact error you were getting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the PHP variable to javascript.

To do so print it in the javascript block:

```
<script>
val = '<?=$yourPhpVariable?>';
</script>
```

Then you will be able to display alert based on whatever the PHP variable is.

If you want to style the alert, use twitter bootstrap or jquery ui, or other javascript UI library.

Comment: Please don't use `<=` and `<?` anymore, short_tags are deprecated. use `<?php echo`.

Comment: @JohannesH. Short tags are enabled in php 5.4 by default and they are not deprecated.

Comment: @JohannesH. Exactly, short-tags are discouraged, but by no way deprecated.

Comment: @FilipGórny Sorry, I didn't realize that 5.4 now separates `<?` and `<?=` and has different options for both - while short echo tags are nabled, traditional short open tags are not. Still running 5.3, therefore I didn't notice. Thanks fpr the update!

Answer (score -2):

I typically use https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ to do this.  You can have the content based on ajax.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
open: function( event, ui ) {
  //Do a ajax call to get the inform from the server
}
});
```

Comment: You DO realize that the OP already linked to that exact plugin, right?

Comment: @JohannesH.  Opps.  No I did not notice. But he didn't describe how he was going to use it in his post.